# vscode builtin node binary like atom

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi in atom we got builtin node and npm binary without installing in the OS that can be call from extension.

This is the path of the default binary in atom

```
/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/npm
/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/npx
```

Does VSCode provide it ?

We have a strict rule not to cluttering our development computer with any unnecessary binary ( e.g we use docker for php, using virtualenv for python and node related project )

In our case for our web development ( php and python mainly ) we use babel to transpile all our file.js on save, in atom we use **language-babel** extension that allow us to transpile using atom node but with project node_modules package. So our babel dependencies is install inside a project and not clutter the OS, and doesn't disturb other project.

On VSCode babel extension I check they don't have this capabilities. Any info on this or is this not do able in VSCode ?

Comment: Just comment on “cluttering” dev box. If your product development requires Node then installing Node  is not cluttering. You can configure VSCode to use Docker container with Node installation rather than your workstation.

Comment: I'm still thinking will it fast enough to transpile single file using docker. Development usually Edit Save Transpile then check browser then edit again and so on.

NodeJS project are easy since it already has all the tools in the virtualenv, but not other language that also build for web ( react , jsx on view part )

Comment: For production it's easy we just mount all the folder to docker and transpile everything in that folder on one go. For development kinda ...

Comment: Anyway you should not rely on Node shipped with any editor. In case of Atom this was mainly for Atom itself so it could run, not for developers. You probably want to have Node _that you will have in production_ (e.g. official stable release) installed on devbox. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I only use the node for babel transpile single file to speed up dev :D, the other stuff such as deployment packaging all done in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest setup in vscode / codium for non nodejs project

OS only require to install nodejs for running babel ( npm , npx not require )
All node package inside project is install using docker
example using Makefile

```bash
SHELL := /bin/bash
THIS_FILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
PROJECT_NAME := "$$(basename `pwd` | cut -d. -f1 )"

yarn:
 docker run --rm -it \
  -v $$(pwd)/${PROJECT_NAME}:/srv/${PROJECT_NAME} \
  -w /srv/${PROJECT_NAME} \
  -e NODE_ENV=development \
  --user $$(id -u):$$(id -g) \
 node:lts-slim yarn $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

init and install babel inside project

```bash
make yarn init
make yarn -- add -D @babel/cli
make yarn -- add -D @babel/core
make yarn -- add -D @babel/preset-react
make yarn -- add -D babel-preset-minify
```

Create ${workspaceRoot}/.babelrc

```json
{
    "comments" : false,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "only": [
        "./asset/js/src"
    ],
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        ["minify", {
            "mangle" : true,
            "builtIns": false,
            "keepClassName" : true
        }]
    ]
}
```

Create ${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label" : "Babel Watch",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "none",
            "command" : "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel",
            "args" : [
                "${workspaceRoot}/asset/js/src/",
                "--config-file=${workspaceRoot}/.babelrc",
                "--out-dir=${workspaceRoot}/asset/js/dist/",
                "--watch"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then Enable Automatic tasks in folder to run on folder open

1. Press F1
2. Search Tasks: Manage Automatic Task in Folder
3. Select Tasks: Manage Automatic Task in Folder
4. Select Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder

On next reopen folder / project babel will watch the folder specify in tasks

It looks like there is no way to allow automatic task in folder from .vscode/settings.json so need enable this on every project once in their own dev computer

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run VS Code without Node, which does suggest it has Node baked in. However, at this time (June 2022) you can't debug or run JavaScript on Node until you install Node separately.

Separate installation decouples your editor dependencies from your code dependencies.

- Your code can debug/run on a version of Node that differs from the version VS Code uses.
- Those not using Node are not obliged to install the CLI toolchain for it.

VS Code supports a multitude of languages. Baking in their toolchains would make it enormous.

Comment: So this means I have to install node in OS level to use similar approach ?

Comment: Yes.  This is also true for git.

Comment: So my best approach is install node npx npm on OS level , and watch the file using task ? Any good on save babel transpile extension out there ?

Comment: That's a completely separate question. The answer is yes, but you will also need to learn to configure your environment. Any major search engine can provide you with answers and walk-through video.

Comment: Most of the tutorial and example is in the case of nodejs project :( they disregard other language